# How do I change the style for only certain text?

Tags: html, css, styles

When I try changing the properties of text using CSS it seems to change all of the text.

I tried putting the css in different divs and styles.

```
<!-- CSS -->
<style>
h1 }
color; #fffff
}
</style>

<!-- HTML -->
<h1>Hey Guys, I'm White Text!</h1>

<h1>Hey Guys I'm Normal Text!</h1>
```

I expected the "Im normal text" to be normal text, while the "I'm White Text" stays white. How can I differentiate these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have specified style for the h1 tag, style of both statements will change. Try specifying class for a tag and then writing your CSS.

```
<!-- CSS -->
<style>
.test{
color: #ffffff;
}
</style>

<!-- HTML -->
<h1 class="test">Hey Guys, I'm White Text!</h1>

<h1>Hey Guys I'm Normal Text!</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

The h1 selector in your CSS will apply to all h1's in the DOM. Instead, try a psudeo class selector:

```
h1:first-of-type {
color; #fffff
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty easy. You just need to crate a style that depends on the class.

There are 3 common ways to connect a tag with your style.

First one is like you did. A style that goes to all h1 tags.

Second is by the tag's ID:
For this one you need to add # before the name of the style. It will look like this

```
#ThisStyleWillBePassedById { 
Color: #ffffff;}
```

Third one is by the tag's class (this is the most common way):
For this one you need to add . before the name of the style. It will look like this

```
.ThisStyleWillBePassedByClass { 
Color: #ffffff;}
```

Then your html will look like this

```
<h1 class="ThisStyleWillBePassedByClass">Hey Guys, I'm White Text!</h1> 


<h1 id="ThisStyleWillBePassedById">Hey Guys I'm Normal Text!</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can differentiate by adding `class` or `id` to `H1` tag.
example :

```
<!-- CSS -->
<style>
h1.white {
color; #fffff
}
</style>

<!-- HTML -->
<h1 class="white">Hey Guys, I'm White Text!</h1>

<h1>Hey Guys I'm Normal Text!</h1>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- inline (html ) -->
<p style="color: red"> I'm red (CSS STYLE FOR INLINE ) </p>
<!-- FOR DOCUMENT(INSIDE THE HTML PAGE - WITHIN <STYLE></STYLE> TAG ) LEVEL -->
<style type="text/css">.blue{ color: blue;}</style>
<h2>I'M BLUE. BY DOCUMENT LEVEL STYLE</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .blue
  {
    color: blue;
  }
  .red
  {
    color: red;
  }
```

```html
<p> ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna <span class="blue">blue</span> Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <span class="red">red</span> sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```